# Instalar MySQL desde el codigo fuente en Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Saludos, soy novato en el uso de los sistemas GNU/Linux y estoy teniendo problemos para instalar en programa MySQL desde el código fuente.

Si alguien pudiera ofrecerme instrucciones o un enlace a una guia detallada le estaria bastante agradecido.

Mi versión de Ubuntu es la 16.04 de 64 bits y la versión de MySQL me resulta indiferente.

Gracias.

Comment: Sería de ayuda indicar que tipo de "problemas" estás teniendo para poder ayudarte mejor. Aparte de esto, tienes la guía de instalación de MySQL:
[Guía MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-fresh-install)
Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido sobre [es.stackoverflow.com](http://www.es.stackoverflow.com) ! Puede obtener más ayuda si muestra dónde está atrapado por capturas de pantalla o explicaciones detalladas. No estoy seguro de dar una respuesta que haga referencia a tutoriales es el propósito del foro. A precisar.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tardes, te dejo un enlace con todo correctamente explicado y sencillo sobre cómo instalarlo, cualquier duda comunícamelo y te ayudo. Saludos.

[Guía para instalar MySQL](http://xtornasol512.obolog.es/instalar-mysql-ubuntu-consola-252576)